# Editing assembly language to bypass the condition

Tags: ida, dll, hex, assembly

I want to edit the compiled DLL code to bypass the variable checking condition. I tried to change the value in the condition but it causes an application crash. How can I "remove" this condition?

Here is the condition (if statement)
[image]

And here is ASM code
[image]

I was trying change the HEX from
`83 F8 FF`
to
`83 F8 01`
but application crashes.

I don't want crack anything, i want remove version checked because library is older than actual game version

Comment: and after the change, is everything looks ok in the disassembly? It might be that there are some checks that detects modifications and crash the game

Comment: It may not be that easy. Possibly the data initialised is used later on, in `sub_180005AD0` for example, and since it doesn't contain what the program expects, it crashes. Try to debug the patched version: put a breakpoint at `1800060EA` and keep pressing `F8` (step over) until it crashes. You will find the procedure causing error.